# Making Headers bold in the outputted csv file in powershell script

Tags: powershell

How do I make my headers bold when they get outputted in my code below:

```
$Header = "Account,Ace String,Object Path"
```

And if I want this last line to be outputted under the same column header within csv, how do i do that:

```
$OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
```

I want ($ACL.AccessControlType, $ACL.IsInherited, $ACL.InheritanceFLags and $ACL.Propagations flagsto be displayed under the column header of Object Path.

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here.

For the first: The CSV file format has no styling/formatting capabilities. It's just plain text, with delimited columns. IOW, what you're asking can't be done if you want to keep using CSV output.

For the second: You're breaking your CSV file by having more columns of data than you do in your headers. This is going to prove to be a mess.

Better solution: Pull all your data together into a collection of objects (a 2-dimensional array, basically), then pipe that collection through `export-csv`

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, let me try and create a 2 dimensional array for outputting the file.